# codeigniter ajax simple form validation

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a simple codeigniter ajax form validation. When the fields are empty, my code is showing the proper error, but when the fields are filled with values, it is still showing empty filled errors.

Here's my code.

controller:

```
class Jsondemo extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('jsondemo_view');
    }
    public function check()
    {
        $name = $this->input->post('nm');
        $password = $this->input->post('ps');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==false)
        {
            $errors = validation_errors();
            echo json_encode(["error" => $errors,"status" => 0 //0 == false]);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(["success" => 'Record Check Successfully!',"status" => 1 // 1 == true]);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my view:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jsondemo/check" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></span>
            <span class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="nm">
            <!-- <span class="text-danger"></span>   -->
        </div><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" id="ps">
            <!-- <span class="text-danger"></span> -->  
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" id="abc">    
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#abc').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var name = $('#nm').val();
            var password = $('#ps').val();

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'jsondemo/check',
                data : {nm : name, ps : password},
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(d)
                {
                    if(d.status == 1)
                    {
                        $('.alert-success').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.alert-danger').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.alert-success').html(d.success);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.alert-danger').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.alert-success').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.alert-danger').html(d.error);
                    }}});});});
</script>
```

Can you help me find the problem?

Comment: Why are you repeating yourself repeating yourself?

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't allow me to ask question with minimum description thats why I'm repeated my question.

Comment: That was a clue that you should make sure you include as much description as possible about what you want to do, what you have tried, what research you've done, and what results you get. See [ask].

Comment: Remember that all browser have developer mode where you can inspect and inject values into forms and pages. Test your assertions about how this is working.

Comment: I'm using  console log but when I'm enter some value to text field and submit its shows field required errors. Im just don't understand what's is wrong in my code.

Comment: You should check your logic in `check()`. Have you proven to yourself that the form validation is actually doing what you think it is? Are you sure that the form validation routines you are using are working? Are you calling them correctly. Don't just think this is the case. *Know* it by testing assertions. Example, what does `$this->form_validation->run()` actually return in all cases? Don't assume you know.

Answer (score 0):

Use form_open("your form action") or form_open_multipart("your form action") instead of 
form tag.

Refer below URL

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Rules need to have the same name as your $_POST names...

So one fix, and a bad one as I hate abbreviations, is to change your field names in your rules to match your form.

i.e.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nm','Name','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ps','Password','required');
```